# SQITCH DEPLOY failing with error: "mysql.exe" unexpectedly returned exit value 1

Tags: mariadb, sqitch

I am running a windows server with MySQL I installed together with XAMPP - MySQL  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.4.11-MariaDB, for Win64 (AMD64), source revision 7c2c420b70b19cc02b5281127205e876f3919dad

When I run `sqitch deploy` I keep getting error - "mysql.exe" unexpectedly returned exit value 1 and a lot of other version information about MySQL in screenshot below:

[image]

What can I do to resolve error please?

Comment: There is no error message in the attached image. Also, not sure how this is a programming question.

Comment: @Shadow Command window had scroll so couldnt take full screenshot. Error is: (“mysql.exe” unexpectedly returned exit value 1)

Sqitch is a database versioning tool I use together with git to keep track of changes in my database. You can find it here: https://sqitch.org/

Comment: You have two applications interacting with each other, you are not writing any code. Hence my point around this not being a programming related question. I would report this as a bug on sqitch's support forum along with the relevant error from mariadb's error log. Btw, mariadb is a fork of mysql, not mysql, which often is the root cause for errors if a product was developed for mysql.